# Strongloop order by related data

Tags: rest, strongloop

I'm trying to order a request by relational data but I can't get it working:

Model 1:

```
{
    "name": "model1",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "properties": {
        "prop1": "string"
    },
    "relations": {
        "model1": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "model2",
            "foreignKey": "model2"
        }
    }
}
```

Model 2:

```
{
    "name": "model2",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "properties": {
        "prop2": "string"
    }
}
```

The REST API request filter I'm trying is this:

```
{
    "include": [
        {
            "relation": "model2",
            "scope": {
                "order": "model2.prop2 ASC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get an error but the list is still unordered.

Any hints?